# React-Enzyme testing- DropDown not rendering properly

Tags: enzyme, react-bootstrap

I have a React DropDown

```
import React from 'react'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import {FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl} from 'react-bootstrap'

class dropDown extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    inputValue: '',
    dropdownText: 'Dropdown'
  };
  static propTypes = {
    dropdownText: PropTypes.string.isRequired
  };
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {inputValue: ''}
  }

  render () {
    return <div>
      <FormGroup controlId="locale-value">
        <ControlLabel>{this.props.dropdownText}</ControlLabel>
        <FormControl componentClass="select" value={this.state.inputValue}>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </FormControl>
      </FormGroup>
    </div>
  }
}

export default dropDown
```

I am now trying to test it using Enzyme

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import LocaleDropDown from './LocaleDropDown'
import ReactTestUtils from 'react-dom/test-utils'
import {FormGroup, ControlLabel, FormControl} from 'eui-components'
import { shallow, mount } from 'enzyme'
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer'

/*
 * Verify that the app can be rendered without any fatal errors.
 */
describe('<dropDown/> component', () => {


  it('renders the Select component', () => {
    const div = document.createElement('div')
    const wrapper = ReactDOM.render(<LocaleDropDown />, div)
    console.log(wrapper.find('select').length.to.equal(1));
  });
});
```

It says wrapper.find is not a function.

Since I am rendering, I was expecting the dropdown to be rendered and able to access all the options inside.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a naming issue.  You don't show where you've defined the `LocaleDropDown` component.  Your first file only exports a component called `dropDown`.

Assuming that the first file is named `LocaleDropDown`, you should change the import statement at the top of the test file.

```
import dropDown from './LocaleDropDown'
```

For what it's worth, I would use the enzyme `shallow` function to mount the component, seeing as how you're already importing it.

Your test could look something like:

```
/*
 * Verify that the app can be rendered without any fatal errors.
 */
describe('<dropDown/> component', () => {
    const dropDown = () => {
        return shallow(<dropDown />);
    }

    it('renders the Select component', () => {
        const select = dropDown().find('select');
        expect(select.length).toEqual(1);
    });
});
```

Comment: No That does not work. I am able to access the defaultProps from the test but not the DropDown

Comment: sinon.spy(LocaleDropDown.prototype, 'componentDidMount');
const wrapper = mount(<LocaleDropDown />)
expect(wrapper.find('select').length).toEqual(1);                                       
  This works but I am still unable to access the options inside